# Using ffmpeg to split MP3 file to multiple equally sound length files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

How to use the command line tool ffmpeg on Windows to split a sound file to multiple sound files without changing the sound properties same everything each one is fixed 30 seconds length. I got this manual example from here:

```
ffmpeg -i long.mp3 -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:30 half1.mp3
ffmpeg -i long.mp3 -acodec copy -ss 00:00:30 -t 00:00:30 half2.mp3
```

But is there a way to tell it to split the input file to equally sound files each one is 30 seconds and the last one is the remaining what ever length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the segment muxer.

```
ffmpeg -i long.mp3 -acodec copy -vn -f segment -segment_time 30 half%d.mp3
```

Add `-segment_start_number 1` to start segment numbering from 1.

Comment: Perfect solution. one more issue, the %d count start from 0, can we make it start from say 1 instead.